# Why my php bind param code can run on wamp, but it didn't work on lnmp platform

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is quite simple.It is about submit some data to mysql database. It did work to use normal way to submit data like query().
Code is here:

```
$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','xxx','xxx','xxx');
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (Nickname, Content, Img) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $nickname, $comments, $proc_comments);
$stmt->execute();
```

When I submitted to this php webpage, it did not pointing out any mistakes.
I'm a university student who are not majoring CS or other relative subjects.Please help me.Thanks.

Update:
This following code can work on the lnmp platform.

```
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','user','passwd','database_name');
    $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $stmt=$con->prepare("UPDATE comments SET Likes=Likes+1 WHERE Num=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$favor_num);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Last update:
I try to check Nginx's error log to see if there is any mistake I missed, but it did not have any problem relative to this strange thing.

Comment: Try $con->error to check if any error occurs but not displaying . More at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: These is no error occurs. I even check nginx's error log to see if there is any mistake I missed, but no error occurs.

Comment: What exactly *doesn't* work? What is happening or not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be many things, but since you have different results on different environments, the two most likely causes are:

1. Your lnmp platform wasn't compiled with mysqli support. Check by creating a page called 'phpinfo.php' with only `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Load that page in your browser, and make sure there's a section with 'mysqli' as its title. Read its description and verify it's there.
2. Your connection data is different on LNMP. It could be as simple as the database name, user name, and password are different on your LNMP box and need to be reconfigured. Go to a terminal, and type `mysql -u <username> -p <databasename>` then when prompted verify you can query the database (e.g. do a `SHOW TABLES;`, `SELECT * FROM comments`, etc.) If you can query it, but you can't manually run that 'INSERT INTO...' from above, then your user is setup but doesn't have correct permissions to do an insert on that table. Google around for MySQL help with configuring that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it seems not the reason you mentioned above.I can submit my data to mysql by 'INSERT INTO' way and mysqli support is normal.

Comment: And I found something quite strange.Some previous code can work by using 'stmt' way.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly wrong:

```
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Charsets in MySQL aren't denoted as strings, but as literals:

```
$con->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

So that query failed, and the charset was not set, and hence you may run into problems trying to insert certain strings. You really should use the mysqli API for this to begin with though:

```
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

Beyond this, it's unclear what exactly "doesn't work" or what other pitfalls there may be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've the way you mentioned before. But it didn't work.

Comment: dosen't work means that I tried to submit some data like the value of $nickname, $comments, $proc_comments to database and checked there is no log that I submitted before.But when I use the normal way , it worked.

Comment: Try some debugging. `var_dump()` all relevant variables and results of function calls.

Comment: Normail way means:$sql="INSERT INTO comments (Nickname, Content, Noimg) VALUES ('$nickname', '$comments', '$proc_comments')";
$con->query($sql);
$con->close();